# How do you keep mongo running on a remote server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh, amazon-web-services

When running mongo on a remote aws server (ubuntu) what is the best way to keep a mongo instance running after sshing to it to start it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/157705/how-can-i-run-mongod-in-the-background-on-unix-mac-osx). In short, you should use `mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log`

Comment: so something like, nohup mongod?

Comment: it looks like that mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log should work...so no need for nohup...have just tried and modifying my answer

Comment: how about "--logappend" ?

Comment: This one works well. Just FYI, to kill the process, you may use the following commands in the interactive shell:

use admin; db.shutdownServer();

Answer (score 8):

Start it as a service. Here's the command

`sudo service mongod start`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the auto-generated init script if you installed the -10gen distro:  http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I can't start it, I just cant keep it running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screen` too for this purpose.

First execute the command

```
screen
```

Then run your server using

```
mongod --dbpath=/example/dbpath
```

Then detach it by pressing ctrl+a and then pressing `d`

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB documentation has two useful links

Installing on Ubuntu

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

Starting and stopping MongoDB

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo

You need to use the --fork and --log parameters to detach the process from the ssh login.